# Distinguish the output link of a Condition node

Tags: flowchart, gojs

I am new to gojs and trying to play with [flowchart example](https://gojs.net/latest/samples/flowchart.html). The current example can't differentiate the output nodes of a **Condition** node and i want to fix it. Is there any way to distinguish them other than simple labeling them?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for pointing out the error in the sample.  We have fixed the code in the sample -- please look again at the latest code at https://gojs.net/latest/samples/flowchart.html.